# How to Retrieve data from DB2 Clob?

Tags: xml, db2

I have a Column with XML - XMLMESSAGE

Sample XML in CLOB :

```
<xml>
 <attribute>name</attribute>
 <value>this is my xml</value>
 <logLocation>/user/apps/myLogFolder</logLocation>
 <engines>
    <engine>
        <engineName>Engine1</engineName>
        <engineLocation>$HOME/apps/engines</engineLocation>
        <engineVersion>3.1416</engineVersion>
    </engine>
    <engine>
        <engineName>Engine2</engineName>
        <engineLocation>$HOME/apps/engines/backup</engineLocation>
        <engineVersion>3b</engineVersion>
    </engine>
</engines>
<connections>
    <connection>
    <jdbc>jdbc:db2://127.0.0.1:50000/localdb</jdbc>
    <user>dbuser</user>
    <password>{}</password>
    </connection>
</connections>
```

I want to retrieve value @ XPATH :
/xml/engines/engine/engineName

Earlier I was using XMLEXTRACT in Oracle and was wondering is DB2 have similar function.
I have gone through few answers on this topic but was not able to get the solution.

Comment: Is it a CLOB or XML type column? And I assume it is DB2 LUW.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi i tried to recreate your problem , i added end tag for xml node

```
CREATE table work.dd(int id, doc clob);

insert into work.DD VALUES (1,'<xml>
 <attribute>name</attribute>
 <value>this is my xml</value>
 <logLocation>/user/apps/myLogFolder</logLocation>
 <engines>
   <engine>
    <engineName>Engine1</engineName>
    <engineLocation>$HOME/apps/engines</engineLocation>
    <engineVersion>3.1416</engineVersion>
</engine>
<engine>
    <engineName>Engine2</engineName>
    <engineLocation>$HOME/apps/engines/backup</engineLocation>
    <engineVersion>3b</engineVersion>
</engine>
</engines>
  <connections>
     <connection>
     <jdbc>jdbc:db2://127.0.0.1:50000/localdb</jdbc>
     <user>dbuser</user>
    <password>{}</password>
    </connection>
</connections>
</xml>')
```

then your query should look like this

```
select * from work.dd,
XMLTABLE(
    '$d/xml/engines/engine' PASSING XMLPARSE(DOCUMENT doc) AS "d"
    COLUMNS
    engineName varCHAR(100) PATH 'engineName'
)
```

I tested it in lUW 10.1